# Proxy Servlet for HTTPS

Tags: java

I have a secure site that needs to display images coming from external non-https URLs on certain pages. I want to create a servlet that is used only as a proxy to pass the image data to the pages. One way is to use Apache's HttpClient to download the image data and then use IOUtils.copy to copy the data to the servlet's response.

Is there a simpler way?

UPDATE: The reason for this is to avoid browser warnings.

Comment: Just use HTTPS URLs to refer to the external resources.

Comment: The external sources are only available on http URLs.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That would be most unusual.

Comment: @EJP It's very common. Not every service offers its content via SSL. For example, in my case, I'm displaying images from the Bing Image API which only offers http URLs for its thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String url = request.getParameter("url");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLogger.log(e);
        }
    }
```

If anyone has a better way to accomplish this, please post it.

Comment: This is a pretty risky technique because you're allowing anyone to proxy any site via yours, just by modifying the `?url=` parameter. What happens if malicious users set the URL to malware or pornography? You should do some kind of validation that the URL is permitted, rather than accept anything. This security risk is ranked number 10 on the OWASP Top 10 Web Application Security Risks list, see http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202010.pdf for more details.

Comment: This is just sample code illustrating only the part I'm asking a question about, not production code. Also, this page is in an authenticated area (that's why I needed the https URLs). That said, thanks for reminding me about validating the url parameter before accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you don't need anything like that, just return the references to the images or audio, or anything else in your HTML response and the browser will take care of make request to the server that contains each of the resources, if they're reachable, they will be displayed on the client.

Comment: I would assume @Raphy doesn't like the warning the browser would display about mixing secure and non-secure content and that's why the servlet proxy idea