# Replace external image url

Tags: servlets, jsf-2.2

I have an image link:

```
http://image.externaldomain.com/someimage.jpg
```

And I want to rewrite that image to be rendered as :

```
http://www.mydomainexample.com/images/someimage.jpg
```

Is this possible without downloading the image on the server and then stream it from my own server?

Comment: So you actually want a streaming proxy functionality? Not something for JSF. Maybe in servlets  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867012/proxy-servlet-for-https or  http://www.adrianwalker.org/2009/09/http-proxy-servlet.html

Comment: you could try ocpsoft url rewriter http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/.  the correct way to add static images in JSF is by putting the resources file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa .  for dynamic images you probably need a servlet http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html